# How to dismiss a presented UIAlertController before displaying another in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I want to dismiss the `UIAlertControllers` that were previously presented before presenting a new `UIAlertController`. I need to do this from the `AppDelegate`. How can this be done. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This smells like you might be cooking spaghetti code over there, care to clarify why this is happening and needs to be done in App Delegate?

Comment: But if you tap the button, dispatch_async to main thread and present a new one you should be good

Comment: Hmm, I present a UIAlertController every time there is a notification message. I want to notify the user when they are inside the app as well. Sometimes there is more than one notification at a time and there is no way of knowing definitely how many would really come. Clicking buttons on every UIAlertController is cumbersome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could find the top presented view controller and check to see if it's a `UIAlertController`. If it is, then you could call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` on it. All of this could be done pretty simply from the app delegate.

Comment: This works:       

     if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]])  
        {  
            [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];  
        }

Answer (score 0):

This should help, you can expand it to the cycle for all view controllers and views:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?